# Ubuntu run python script on system startup that is using Firefox

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, firefox

I wrote python script that uses `subprocess.pOpen()` module to run and manipulate with 2 GUI programs: Firefox and VLC player. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS operating system in Desktop mode.

My problem is when I try to run that python script when system starts, script is running but Firefox or VLC don't start.

So far, I tried to make shell script to run my python script and then with `crontab` with `@reboot /home/user/startup.sh` to execute my python script. I set all permissions for every script that is using. I gave my user root permisions so everything is OK with that.

I also tried to run my script putting command `"sudo python /path/to/my/script.py"` in `/etc/rc.local` file but that also is not helping.

I googled and found out people using `.desktop` files that they put in `~/.config/autostart/` directory but that also failed. Example of what I wrote:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec="sudo python /home/user/path_to_my_script/my_script.py"
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=screensplayer
Comment=screensplayer
```

And I saved this as `program.desktop` in `~/.config/autostart/` directory but it does not work. I am sure there is a way to fix this but don't know how. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to my problem. When you are running commands with `pOpen` in python like this:

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
_FIREFOX_START = ["sudo", "firefox", "test.com/index.html"]
subprocess.Popen(self._FIREFOX_START, stdout=self.FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

it won't run apps because of "`sudo`" word, when I removed it, it worked.

Also run gnome-session-properties in terminal and add new startup application, be aware that you have to execute python script without sudo, like this:

```
python /home/user/path_to_script/script.py
```

Also, I granted my user root privileges so kepp that in mind.